# Rails won't use my version of Ruby on my environment [Windows, using uru not rvm]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

**Problem:** I needed use `ruby 2.3.1` from what I currently use which is `ruby 2.2.4`. When I do `ruby -v`, it shows `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x64-mingw32]`. I use uru as an alternative for rvm.

However, when I do `rails s`, it tells me `Your Ruby version is 2.2.4, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1`. `bundle` tells me the same thing.

`uru ls` shows:

`224p230     : ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]
231p112     : ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x64-mingw32]`

I've gone through every thread before posting. I have the latest version of Rails and Ruby from RailsInstallers.

Here's what I've tried:

1. Delete the Ruby folder from RailsInstaller directory. => `rails s is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`
2. Delete and replace the old Ruby with the new Ruby directory => same thing

Contemplating that this is a RailsInstaller error.

**Edit:** I've changed the Gemfile to use my version of Ruby. It's a sloppy solution for now, but I'm gonna reinstall Rails altogether when I'm finished with this project.

Comment: have you tried by running `bundle update` and `bundle install` after changing the Gemfile.?

Comment: What does `uru ls`say within your rails directory?

Comment: `224p230     : ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]                   
231p112     : ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x64-mingw32]`

Comment: There should be something like a `=>` symbol, which shows you, which ruby is currently selected. I haven't worked with `uru` before, but I suspect you need a `.ruby-version` file, which sets the correct ruby version within your rails project. At least, that's how it works with `rvm` and `rbenv`.